# Select between multiple lines

Tags: sql

I have this situation:

I need to select data from tableA where its foreign key refers to tableB
like: **tableA.tableB_id = tableB id informed**

OR

the second restriction refers to postal code informed on tableB, there is initial postal code and final postal code in tableB, and a single postal code on tableA.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    tableB_id INTEGER,
    postalCode varchar(10)
);

CREATE TABLE tableB (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    InitialPostalCode varchar(10),
    FinalPostalCode varchar(10)
);
```

Table B is a **LIST** of locations with multiple initial and final postal codes

I need to select from tableA where tableB_id = tableB.id **OR** tableA.cep is **between** tableB.InitialPostalCode and tableB.FinalPostalCode

```
SELECT
    id,
    postalCode
FROM
    tableA
WHERE
    tableB_id = ID
    OR postalCode BETWEEN...


SELECT
    InitialPostalCode,
    FinalPostalCode
FROM
    tableB
WHERE
    id = some ID;
```

how can I merge these two queries?

thanks everyone!

Comment: `join on b.id=a.b_id or a.cep between b.initial and b.final`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT a.id, a.postalCode
FROM tableA a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableB b WHERE b.id = a.tableB_id) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableB b WHERE a.cep BETWEEN b.InitialPostalCode AND b.FinalPostalCode);
```

I prefer to use `EXISTS` because:

- You only want columns from `tableA`, so `tableB` does not *need* to be in the `FROM` clause.
- Each subquery can be optimized with appropriate indexes.
- There is no reason to remove duplicates after the processing.
- `OR` in `ON` clauses can be very inefficient.